# Cannot run a go binary under apache via PHP shell_exec

Tags: php, go, shell-exec

I am having an issue and I don't understand what is going on. I am basically using this PHP script to try and run a go binary :

```
<?php

shell_exec('/go/bin/x -arg -arg etc');
```

If I run this PHP file via command line it works. If I run it directly in browser (it's under www) it does not work. No errors whatsoever.

cli runs as `root` and apache as `www-data`. I have set the permissions to `0777` for `/go/bin/x` and I have also changed the owner / group to `www-data`. Still nothing.

What can cause this behavior ?

Also note that `shell_exec` works, but so far I have only ran other php files.

Comment: What does _"it does not work"_ mean? Error message? Error return value?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of shell_exec, so how can you tell that "it does not work"?

Comment: @Peter @icza The go script should execute and write a file and it does not write it. This takes some time and by default I ran it with nohup and another process should start so I can see it in `ps aux`. And the process is never started. I wrote the question like this to be easier. The go process never starts regardless of if I use it with `nohup` or not, that's what I mean with it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how I did not think about this before... The issue was that 1 of the input args contained a location to a text file and apache did not have the rights to read the file. The error was in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0):

To Whom It May Concern.

I have same issue that I cannot run shell_exec/exec via website even they were run well in terminal.

See log:

```
[13-Jul-2020 19:57:23 UTC] PHP Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /...test_script.php on line 3
```

**Case 1**: Check all php.ini where disable_function does not contain "shell_exec" or "exec"

```
$ sudo find / -name "php.ini"

$ sudo cat <path_to_php.ini> | grep disable_functions

// disable_functions = <<= This is OK

// disable_functions = "shell_exec, exec, system...." <<= They are disabled
```

Remove function that you want to use. Don't forget restart server.

---

**Case 2**: If disable_functions are all empty for all php.ini. Check your PHP-FPM on your hosting via Cpanel. Go to "MultiPHP Manager" from your Cpanel and check PHP-FPM status on your domain. Turn it off and you will be able to run shell_exec();

[image]